# Quantifying how much would Jupiter heat up if you accelerate Jupiter out of orbit around the sun using fusion candles?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, planets, rocket-science

So, I responded to a post of someone saying that you could turn Jupiter into a spaceship using fusion candles. I mentioned that doing so would dramatically heat up the planet, especially if you were to accelerate it out of orbit of the sun over the course of decades, even centuries if needed. Someone else jumped in and claimed that the black body radiation of the planet would keep the temperature nominal. Furthermore the time period of acceleration applied would not be a significant factor because the temperature of the planet would reach "equilibrium". I thought this was absurd considering the amount of energy required to accelerate Jupiter with this method, as it was claimed these candles would be fusing hydrogen and helium of the atmosphere of Jupiter and blasting the resulting fusion plasma down on the planet at .5c to provide the acceleration. And while of course there would likely be some max temperature Jupiter would reach where the amount of thermal radiation would be equal to the amount these candles add to Jupiter, that temperature would be quite significant. Much much higher than the current temperature of the planet.

I need everyone's help to settle the debate. Maths/Calculation would be greatly appreciated! (here is a website I found that covers the basic idea: https://www.orionsarm.com/eg-article/6036af70d08fd)

(I posted this question here once and it was closed and told it was an engineering question. So I posted it on SE Engineering and it was closed and I was told it was a SE Physics question. I agree and this is more of a physics question. Please don't close it, would really like to know the answer.)

Comment: It is much easier to use the Sun as a spaceship. It would be great to move around at a whopping 368 km/s with respect to the cosmic microwave background! Of course it is too hot, so we could live on a planet nearby in its Goldilocks zone.

Comment: [Previously on Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/706237/44126); [previously on Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/50804/8516). I’m not really sure this question fits on either site.  Some space-engineering stuff fits better on [space.se]; you might find questions about the energy associated with de-orbiting planets on [astronomy.se]. Sometimes purely speculative questions find a home on [worldbuilding.se] (but also sometimes not). Not every question has a good home on the SE network.

Comment: After reading your link about “fusion candles”: that’s very interesting device for speculative fiction.  I have lots of questions about whether such a device could actually deliver thrust to a planet. (Not least: the escaping propellant would interact with the planet’s magnetosphere in a very complicated way.) I don’t think this question can be answered here in its present form. But if you’re interested in pursuing the idea, you might be able to come up with some answerable sub-questions.

Comment: One question, why would the jet have to be moving at $0.5c$?  That's very extreme.  You can generate momentum more effectively from moving more mass slowly

Comment: Define a fusion candle. Why does Jupiter get heated dramatically?

Comment: By 'out of orbit', do you mean escaping the solar system permanently or dropping Jupiter into the sun? How quickly are you going to do it? Given those, an assumption about exhaust velocity, and an assumption about how much energy is usable for thrust, it should be pretty easy to calculate heat dissipated in the atmosphere.